# How to use numba in Colaboratory

Tags: numba, google-colaboratory, numba-pro

Anybody tried to use numba in google collaboratory? I just can not figure out how to set it up in this environment. 
At the moment, I'm stuck with the error `library nvvm not found`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy this code into cell. It works for me.

```
!apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
!pip3 install numba

import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = "/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice"
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvvm.so"

from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import time

@cuda.jit
def hello(data):
    data[cuda.blockIdx.x, cuda.threadIdx.x] = cuda.blockIdx.x

numBlocks = 5
threadsPerBlock = 10

data = np.ones((numBlocks, threadsPerBlock), dtype=np.uint8)

hello[numBlocks, threadsPerBlock](data)

print(data)
```

Comment: Do you need `!apt-get -y` as well?

Comment: Also don't forget to use GPU Runtime too. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Comment: Dependencies can be simplified by skipping "recommended" packages by `!apt install -y --no-install-recommends -q nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. It is still huge and slow install, but only 100 packages are installed instead of more than 600, like fonts etc.

Comment: I can confirm that it can not be minimized more. If the package `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` is removed, `numba` will be broken after kernel restart even if all other 99 dependent packages remain installed.

Comment: Installation of the toolkit did not work for me, but luckily when I used the smaller install of @hynekcer it does work somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have to install the packages @Algis suggested, but the paths to the drivers were different. So I had to do the following.

First determine the correct paths for the drivers

```
!find / -iname 'libdevice'
!find / -iname 'libnvvm.so'

# Output:
# /usr/local/cuda-9.2/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so
# /usr/local/cuda-9.2/nvvm/libdevice
```

Then set the paths as @Algis described

```
import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.2/nvvm/libdevice"
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.2/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do @Stan's work in one simple sweep if you have this block at the beginning of your colab notebook (this also automatically updates as CUDA gets updated)

```
import os
dev_lib_path = !find / -iname 'libdevice'
nvvm_lib_path = !find / -iname 'libnvvm.so'
assert len(dev_lib_path)>0, "Device Lib Missing"
assert len(nvvm_lib_path)>0, "NVVM Missing"
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = dev_lib_path[0]
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = nvvm_lib_path[0]
```