# How do I modify my Python Function to be able to use Numba so I can speed it up on a Google Colab GPU / TPU?

Tags: python, numba

I have a python function that is slow and I believe it would be faster if processed on a GPU / TPU. I am using Google Colab. How do I modify it so that I can use Numba to process it on the Google Colab GPU?

```
def Tournament (x, w, cutoff, y):
  preds = np.matmul(x,w)
  preds2 = (preds<np.quantile(preds, 1-cutoff,axis=0))
  preds = (preds>np.quantile(preds, cutoff,axis=0))
  rets = y * preds
  rets[rets == 0] = np.nan
  rets2 = y * preds2
  rets2[rets == 0] = np.nan
  ans = np.nanmedian(rets, axis=0) - np.nanmedian(rets2,axis=0)
  ans = ans[:,None]
  rand2 = np.random.uniform(-0.00000001,0.00000001,size=(popsize,1))
  ans += rand2
  garbage,sort = np.unique(ans,return_index = True)
  sort = sort[:,None]
  return sort, ans
```

I've tried loading the Numba library and using `@jit` before the function but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811248/how-to-use-numba-in-colaboratory) help?

Comment: Doesn't the code have to use Numba operations instead of numpy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1.

```
@vectorize(device="cuda")
```

or 2.

```
@guvectorize(input_data_type, input_array_shape, output_array_shape, device="cuda")
```

or 3.

```
@numba.cuda.jit
```

The first one is easy to implement, but the performance improvement is limited, sometimes even slower.

The second one needs minor modification on the function, I haven't really get this to speed my own functions up, but it's supposed to accelerate any compatible code.

The third one requires major modification of your function code and main code, you will need to manually design the data stream to be copied to and from the GPU device. This one will provide you the best GPU performance.